# Question regarding synthetic UV sources (fluorescent, LED) and claims to "match the sun"

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I am involved with some discussion regarding lamps specifically in use for reptiles. Captive reptiles can often suffer from hyperparathyroidism from a lack of vitamin D. The safest way found to deliver this to reptiles has been through using UV lamps. Supplementation can be difficult with some of these animals and vitamin D toxicity levels are not known.

Some of these lamps state "30% UVA, 12% UVB" and are fluorescent lamps that emit full spectrum lighting. The sun, as I understand it, is only roughly 5% UV with 95% of UV being UVA with only 5% of UV being UVB.

Per the bulb, it seems like 42% of light emitted is UV with 12% being UVB. That seems significantly higher than the sun. The recommended distance for use of these bulbs should produce a UVI of 4-6.

Can I have help understanding what these numbers may mean, what the ratings mean in relation to sunlight, and if they really are "simulating sunlight"?